# For loop the table only, but not actually a table

Tags: excel, vba

```
For b = 6 To .Cells(.Rows.Count, "A").End(xlDown).Row
```

I would like to check each row starting from `A8` to within the table. Please see attached image. How can I make this work?

[image: Table like this]

Comment: So from `A8` to which one?

Comment: Hi Vityata, should be from A6 to A7 at this moment, but user will input rows between that. so i can not fix the row i select to.

Comment: so from the 6. to the first before the first space?

Answer (score 0):

This will show you how to refer to `A6` and `A7`, considering that your logic is the following: "Start from 6 and finish before the first empty row":

```
    With Worksheets(1)        
        For cnt = 6 To .Cells(6, "A").End(xlDown).Row
            Debug.Print cnt
        Next cnt        
    End With
```

And in case that the `6` is determined to be "the first cell with a value after the first empty cell" then something like this will be of use:

```
Public Sub TestMe()

    Dim start   As Long
    Dim cnt     As Long

    With Worksheets(1)        
        start = .Cells(1, "A").End(xlDown).End(xlDown).Row
        For cnt = start To .Cells(start, "A").End(xlDown).Row
            Debug.Print cnt
        Next cnt
    End With

End Sub
```